# Cannot install libextutils-cbuilder-perl - "Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."

Tags: pi-2

I am trying to install sli3er engine on a Raspberry Pi using [this](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/slic3r/) document. However, when I install the dependencies, I got an error here;

**INSTALL COMMAND**: `sudo apt-get install libextutils-cbuilder-perl`

**ERROR**:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
>   libextutils-cbuilder-perl : Depends: perl (>= 5.13.9) but it is not
>   going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held
>   broken packages.

Here is the output of `perl -v`:

> This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 1 (v5.24.1) built for arm-linux-gnueabihf-thread-multi-64int
>   (with 80 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
>
> Copyright 1987-2017, Larry Wall
>
> Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
>   GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.
>
> Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
>   this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
>   Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.

Comment: Could you check the output of `apt list perl`? I wonder if somehow your Perl packages have got mixed up.

Comment: `apt list perl` the result is => **Listing... Done
perl/stable,now 5.24.1-3+deb9u3 armhf [installed]**